# How do I search for a string with 2 patterns in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search log files for a string that must contain 2 patterns, the word "down" and a specific date, but they are not next to each other in the string. Everything I've tried so far has been either down or the date but not necessarily both. Like I said I want the strings that ONLY have both. How would I go about doing this? Preferably in the powershell command line?

Comment: Can you post an example of a string you're trying to match, along with what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Heres a link to technet, a microsoft blog, on how to do that. [powershell documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)

use -pattern to delimit the pattern. -pattern uses string or a regex for the pattern

you need to also add the -path to your log file

```
C:/> select-string -path path/to/file/logname.log -pattern "text or regex"
```

if you have more than 1 log use this

```
C:/> select-string -path path/to/file/*.log -pattern "text or regex"
```

Comment: You should elaborate. Using sources is good, but maybe you could quote the text or show an example using `Select-String`. :-)

Comment: I wasn't trying to give the answer away for this. It's part of learning to discover the answer through trial and error. I linked him/her to the tools needed to accomplish this.

Comment: *Updated added example. the documentation has examples fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a couple ways to go about this that I know of. The RegEx way, and the other way. First the simple way...
(I don't know your date, so I'm using 5/4/13)

```
GC $LogFile | ?{ $_ -match "down" -and $_ -match "5/4/13" }
```

Then with RegEx you could do something like:

```
GC $LogFile | ?{ $_ -match "(down).*?(5/4/13)" }
```

So that looks for the word "down" followed by any number of characters, followed by "5/4/13". The only possibly confusing bit there is the `.*?` part. The dot in regex matches any character except a New Line or Carriage Return character. The * mean zero or more of those characters, and the ? means that it won't take more than is needed before the next match item (5/14/13 in this case). If the date comes first you reverse the order. If you don't know the order, well, then use option 1 or find somebody better at RegEx than me. It can be done without knowing the order, but I can't remember how since I have never used that myself.

**Edit:** Ok, I found the RegEx I was thinking of, because Frode's comment made me realize that it is something I should know because it's better in general, and it bugged me not knowing. So...

Updated RegEx option! This will search for the word "down", and the date "5/4/13" no matter which order they are in, and if it finds one it will only look for the other as its second match. So it'll match `"down <other text> 5/4/13"` and `"5/4/13 <other text> down"`.

```
-match "(down|(5/4/13)).*?(?(2)down|5/4/13)"
```

See these examples that I ran it against:

```
PS C:\> "5/4/13 - SQLSrvr17 went down" -match "(down|(5/4/13)).*?(?(2)down|5/4/13)"
True

PS C:\> "There was downtime on server2 on 5/4/13" -match "(down|(5/4/13)).*?(?(2)down|5/4/13)"
True

PS C:\> "The downtime was due to server 3 being down" -match "(down|(5/4/13)).*?(?(2)down|5/4/13)"
False

PS C:\> "5/4/13 is 5/4/13" -match "(down|(5/4/13)).*?(?(2)down|5/4/13)"
False
```

Usage for a log file would be:

```
GC Logfile.log | ?{ $_  -match "(down|(5/4/13)).*?(?(2)down|5/4/13)" }
```

If that log file contained the 4 lines I tested against the result would be:

```
5/4/13 - SQLSrvr17 went down
There was downtime on server2 on 5/4/13
```

Comment: To support both situations, try: `(down).*?(5/4\/13)|(5/4/13).*?(down)`.